# how to migrate a MERN stack app to Lambda

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a MERN stack app and i am hosting it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with a static IP, but I want to move to Lambda functions so i can save some money.

My backend and frontend is not separated and my database is MongoDB. I couldn't find a guide for my case so my question is, can i migrate my app to Lambda? if yes, is there any complete/easy guide out there to follow?

I have tried:
[deploy-an-express-js-app-to-aws-lambda-using-the-serverless-framework](https://bitbucket.org/blog/deploy-an-express-js-app-to-aws-lambda-using-the-serverless-framework)
and had no luck.

AWS documentation also was complicated:
[Going Serverless: Migrating an Express Application to Amazon API Gateway and AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/going-serverless-migrating-an-express-application-to-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/)

Thank you

Comment: You can start by analyzing your application and identifying which functionality can be ported over to Lambdas. I think it will involve a phased migration and code refactoring.

Comment: You *can* but it doesn't mean you *should*.  A typical MERN stack is not designed for Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is - you cant, at least not a one to one migration i.e. host your entire stack on Lambda.

You'd need to start separating your stack out into at least three defined layers - UI, Logic, Data. For each layer, there is a best practice serverless pattern and implementation to follow.

If you are unfamiliar with AWS Lambda, and distributed/serverless computing as a whole, this is likely to be a very steep learning curve. You'd have to weigh up the pros can cons.

If all you are trying to do is to save some money, why not use AWS EC2 and pick a smaller instance? These are very cheap.

A hybrid approach that could work well is to move your front end/ui onto serverless hosting (AWS Amplify / CloudFront and S3) and keep your backend on a 'server'. This will take some load off your backend, and should make moving to a small instance easy.

If you have any large files/images etc that you host, move them to a SaaS CDN, or create your own with CloudFront and S3.

Next, start migrating your databases to serverless (AWS DynamoDB or AWS Aurora). This will again free up some compute on your backend to reduce costs.

Finally, you can refactor your backend to a web api using AWS Lambda and API Gateway.

Comment: For now im using T2.nano which is very low price. the problem is the load balancer which i need it for my listeners ( https, http ). if i switch to single instance then my app will not work on https.